# Save Email Attachments to a Network location

Tags: vba, outlook

I’m trying to create a VBA macro that saves an email attachment to folder   depending on the email address.  For example if I receive and email with an attachment from joey@me.com I want to save that attachment to the directory 
\server\home\joey
or if I receive it from steve@me.com  the attachment should be saved in
\server\home\steve .

And finally I want send a reply email with the name of the file that has been saved.  I found some code that almost does what I want but I having a difficult time modifying it.  This is all being done in Outlook 2010.  This is what I have so far.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Const mypath = "\\server\Home\joe\"
Sub save_to_v()

    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strPrompt As String, strname As String
    Dim sreplace As String, mychar As Variant, strdate As String
    Set objItem = Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
    If objItem.Class = olMail Then

        If objItem.Subject <> vbNullString Then
            strname = objItem.Subject
        Else
            strname = "No_Subject"
        End If
        strdate = objItem.ReceivedTime

        sreplace = "_"

        For Each mychar In Array("/", "\", ":", "?", Chr(34), "<", ">", "|")

            strname = Replace(strname, mychar, sreplace)
            strdate = Replace(strdate, mychar, sreplace)
        Next mychar

        strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the item?"
        If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
            objItem.SaveAs mypath & strname & "--" & strdate & ".msg", olMSG
        Else
            MsgBox "You chose not to save."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Const mypath = "\\server\Home\"

Sub save_to_v()

    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strPrompt As String, strname As String, strSubj As String, strdate As String
    Dim SaveAsName As String, sreplace As String
    Dim mychar As Variant

    Set objItem = Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    If objItem.Class = olMail Then

        If objItem.Subject <> vbNullString Then
            strSubj = objItem.Subject
        Else
            strSubj = "No_Subject"
        End If

        strdate = objItem.ReceivedTime

        sreplace = "_"

        For Each mychar In Array("/", "\", ":", "?", Chr(34), "<", ">", "|")
            strSubj = Replace(strSubj, mychar, sreplace)
            strdate = Replace(strdate, mychar, sreplace)
        Next mychar

        strname = objItem.SenderEmailAddress

        strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the item?"

        If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
            Select Case strname
            Case "joey@me.com"
                SaveAsName = mypath & "joey\" & strSubj & "--" & strdate & ".msg"
            Case "steve@me.com"
                SaveAsName = mypath & "steve\" & strSubj & "--" & strdate & ".msg"
            End Select

            objItem.SaveAs SaveAsName, olMSG
        Else
            MsgBox "You chose not to save."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It will never work. As Outlook 2010 is not saving any msg file to a network drive only local drive is working !!
As described in the documentation of M$ and tested by me.
Simple test with fixed path and filename.
Local c:\ works. Network drive in UNC or L: does not work !!!!